# How to set a profile picture for the Google Groups Email Address in Google Workspace, so recipients can see the profile picture in their Gmail inbox

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, google-groups

We are using Google Workspace together with Groups for Business as a shared email inbox. The given address *info@example.com* is also used as the email sender.

When people receive our emails from *info@example.com* they see in eg. Gmail only the gray silhouette of a human head.

We would like that the recipients see our
company logo instead. How can this be accomplished?.

What we tried:

- BIMI: Is currently in closed beta, and need certs that one have to buy.
- Creating a personal Gmail account with info@example.com as the address is not possible. Gmail complains that the email is already in use.
- Gravatar Icon does exist but is not picked up by Gmail.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [answer](https://support.google.com/a/thread/12438084?hl=en&msgid=14516157) by LMcKin51- G-Suite-Product Expert, Diamond Product Expert, to [Set avatar or profile picture for G Suite Google Group](https://support.google.com/a/thread/12438084?hl=en&msgid=12438084)

> Groups avator not supported